# Attempting to optimize the following loop over numpy arrays? Best method ? (numba or dask)

Tags: python, numpy, numba, dask-distributed

I am trying to refactor this code in order to minimize its runtime and memory usage (if possible)

```
for i in range(gbl.NumStoreRows):
    cal_effects[i,:,:len(orig_cols)] = cal_effects_vals - **Use ~1gb memory on this line**
    priors[i,:len(orig_cols)] = orig_prior_coeffs
    priors_SE[i,:len(orig_cols)] = orig_prior_SE
```

It is only the first operation in the loop which is time/memory intensive, I tried splitting the the memory/runtime intensive line from the other two and created two separate loops. - just made it a second slower, and no memory impact.

I tried to create a jit function for this code block then, but the application stops running later on in the code with error message. - It just stops on one of the LoadFunctions(), so I think jit might be altering the output or my function is incorrectly structured.

**Variations of my jit function**
**Variation 1**
@jit
def populate_cal_effects(cal_effects_vals):
for i in range(gbl.NumStoreRows):
cal_effects[i,:,:len(orig_cols)] = cal_effects_vals

```
populate_cal_effects(cal_effects_vals)

for i in range(gbl.NumStoreRows):
    priors[i,:len(orig_cols)] = orig_prior_coeffs
    priors_SE[i,:len(orig_cols)] = orig_prior_SE
```

**Variation 2: Adding a return statement to the function**

```
@jit
def populate_cal_effects(cal_effects_vals):
    for i in range(gbl.NumStoreRows):
        cal_effects[i,:,:len(orig_cols)] = cal_effects_vals
    return  cal_effects[i,:,:len(orig_cols)]
```

**Variation 3: add the operations from the other for loop to the function**

- This was the method I expected to be fastest and not affect data output

  ```
    @jit(parallel=True)
    def populate_cal_effects(cal_effects_vals):
    for i in prange(gbl.NumStoreRows):
        cal_effects[i,:,:len(orig_cols)] = cal_effects_vals
        priors[i,:len(orig_cols)] = orig_prior_coeffs
        priors_SE[i,:len(orig_cols)] = orig_prior_SE
  ```
- I wanted to utilize parallel mode and use prange for the loop, but I cannot get this to work.

**Context/Other:**

- I have defined this function inside the main load function. - My next step is too move it out of the Load function and re-run.
- If this method doesn't work I was thinking of trying to process in parallel (multiple cores) - not machines. using Dask.

*Any pointers on this would be great, maybe I am wasting my time and this is not optimizable, if so, do let me know*

**Steps to reproduce**

- gbl.NumstoreRows = 866 (# of stores)
- All data types are numpy arrays

  `cal_effects = np.zeros((gbl.NumStoreRows, n_days, n_cal_effects), dtype=np.float64)`

  `priors = np.zeros((gbl.NumStoreRows, n_cal_effects), dtype=np.float64)`

  `priors_SE = np.zeros((gbl.NumStoreRows, n_cal_effects), dtype=np.float64)`

Comment: Thanks for the question! Especially when talking about numba & dask (but also generally), how your data is structured/defined, what classes/types are involved, and how much data we're talking about really matters. Please try to set up a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example); at the moment we don't even know if `cal_effects` is a numpy array, an xarray dataset, or a custom object! Please provide setup code so we can all be working with the same problem :) Good luck!

Comment: I think you'd get more interest if the code was simple and easy to read, with clearly described variables.  Names like `cal_effects_vals` may be great when using in a large program, but short ones like `x`, `arr`, etc are easier to grasp in code snippets like this.  I for one will move on to another question if I can't grasp the gist of the issue within 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my comment:

```
for i in range(gbl.NumStoreRows):
    cal_effects[i,:,:len(orig_cols)] = cal_effects_vals - **Use ~1gb memory on this line**
    priors[i,:len(orig_cols)] = orig_prior_coeffs
    priors_SE[i,:len(orig_cols)] = orig_prior_SE
```

from this I deduce `cal_effects` is a (N,M,L) shape array; `priors` is (N,L)

```
 big_arr = np.zeros((N,M,L))
 arr = np.zeros((N,L)
 for i in range(N):
     big_arr[i, :, :l] = np.ones((M,l))
     arr[i, :l] = np.ones(l)
```

And apparently `np.ones((M,l))` is large, on the order of 1gb.

Do `cal_effects_vals` and `orig_prior_coeffs` differ with `i`.  It isn't obvious from the code.  If they don't differ, why iterate on `i`?

So this isn't an answer, but it may help you write a question that is more succinct, and attract more answers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will rename variables to make them clearer and more general. But you are correct with the shape cal_effects(N) and the size of  np.ones((M, 1))